# How do i store multiple random values in an array with localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to store multiple values, so I run a function that generates the values and then I store them with localStorage, however, I can't seem to get the values stored. I added in 1, 2 and that seems to work but the randomly generated values don't. From the image, you can see only 2 numbers have stored.

https://gyazo.com/a7180cac935809ca48c244794df3a6ca

```js
$.getJSON("/products.json", function(product) {
  var value = [1, 2];
  console.log(value);

  localStorage["value"] = JSON.stringify(value);

  $.each(product.products, function() {
    var sMin = 5;
    var sMax = 20;

    var randomSelect = sMin + Math.floor(Math.random() * sMax);

    var t = randomSelect.toString();
    value.push(t);
  });
});

var test = JSON.parse(localStorage["value"]);
console.log(test);
```

Comment: Hello, have you tried to move the line `localStorage["value"] = JSON.stringify(value);` to the end of function (after `$.each` call)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this method `localStorage.getItem("key")`.